# JMF and Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jmf

I have installed the JMF for windows (jmf-2_1_1e-windows-i586.exe) from the following link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR

but when I double click on the executable file it unpacked to:
C:\Users...\TEMP

I don't know how to solve this problem.

I need to add the jar files to Netbeans.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed JMF with Netbeans by installing the zip folder cross-platform java from the following link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR

and at NetBeans Project, I added to the project library the following .jar files:

customizer.jar

jmf.jar

mediaplayer.jar

multiplayer.jar

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

During installation the JMF-2.1.1, you can specify destination folder where you want to install the JMF:

[image: Destination Location]

Change the destination folder and install it either to

> C:\Program Files\JMF (for 64 bit JMF)

or

> C:\Program Files(*86)\JMF (for 32 bit JMF)

location according to system requirements. 
After the installation, you can find your jar files at location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib.

You can add your jar files(customizer.jar, jmf.jar, mediaplayer.jar, multiplayer.jar) by choosing the Add jar option under Libraries section in NetBeans.